# How to update a key of a property in firebase relatime database using angular 7

Tags: angular, database, firebase

I am trying to edit the key of a property in my firebase database which i failed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Updating and Deleting Todos

To update or delete a todo, things are a bit different because you’ll need a reference to the todo item that is to be updated or deleted.

This can be done with `AngularFireDatabase.object`. Objects inside a Firebase have a unique key available as `$key`:

Updating Todos
Here’s how you would toggle the completed state of a todo:

```
toggleDone(todo: any): void {
  this.af.object('/todos/' + todo.$key)
    .update({ content: todo.content, done: !todo.done });
}
```

Or update its content:

```
updateTodo2(todo: any, newValue: string): void {
  this.af.object('/todos/' + todo.$key)
    .update({ content: newValue, done: todo.done });    
}
```

for more details goto
https://alligator.io/angular/firebase-crud-operations/

Comment: in the above mentioned example can we able to edit the key of a property, say for example we want to edit the key- 'content' and change it to 'data'.